# Change the value of a variable when an image is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to select one image among four of them. And then the variable that i have should be increased. If i select other image then the variable should change and take the value of that image. Here is the code i have so far that does not work

HTML

```
<div class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="paroxi" value="10"><br>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .checkbox{
width: 23px;
height: 21px;
background: black;
visibility:hidden;

 }
.checked{
background: red;
visibility:block;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(".checkbox").click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('checked')
});
```

Comment: Is each image a checkbox?

Comment: What variable do you have to increase? No variables in your code.

Comment: the variable is the price.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna keep the checkboxes, guess to post price value later, than you can do it this way:

```js
$('.image-selection input').on('change', function(e) {
 $('.selected-value').text( $('.image-selection input:checked').val() );
}).trigger('change');
```

```css
.image-selection input {
    display: none;
}
.image-selection input:checked + img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-selection">
    <label for="checkbox-1">
        <input id="checkbox-1" name="image-input" type="radio" value="10" checked="checked" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </label>
    <label for="checkbox-2">
        <input id="checkbox-2" name="image-input" type="radio" value="20" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </label>
    <label for="checkbox-3">
        <input id="checkbox-3" name="image-input" type="radio" value="30" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </label>
    <label for="checkbox-4">
        <input id="checkbox-4" name="image-input" type="radio" value="40" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </label>
</div>
<p>Price: <span class="selected-value"></span></p>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtj93t4w/1/).